# Cocoa or C/C++ msn library?

Tags: cocoa, msn

I looked for this on the internet but could not find anything. Is there any MSN framework or library? I would like to use it for a Cocoa project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's Libpurple, which is used by the Adium application. Both are GPLv2, so you'll need to license your application under the GPLv2 to use Libpurple.